# Slipt a text with accents passing by argument a text without accents

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to highlight a text following this code:

```
function getHighlightedText(text, highlight) {
  var parts = text.split(new RegExp(`(${highlight})`, 'gi'));
  return parts.map((part, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
      {part.toLowerCase() === highlight.toLowerCase() ? <b style={{ backgroundColor: '#e8bb49' }}>{part}</b> : part}
    </React.Fragment>
  ));
}
```

When I pass as arguments a text with accents and highlight without, I can't get the right return as I want

Exemple 01: getHighlightedText("Avô","avo")
Expected 01: (hightlighted) Avô
Returned 01: nothing

Exemple 02: getHighlightedText("Coração","cao")
Expected 02: (Not Hightlight) Cora (hightlighted) ção
Returned 02: nothing

The problem is when I try to split a text with accents with another there aren't accents my return is unexpected.

Question: Is there any way to put some rule in split to handle this case?
I'm trying to avoid handle with it go through all both string (e.g using For)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm not trying to remover, just trying to split a string with accents with another string that doesnt